# Implementing routes specifically for SPA applications what codebase to use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently in the process of implementing routing that are slim down version for SPA applications and I wonder what codebase should I use? the one that ASP.NET WebAPI is built with or the one that ASP.NET MVC is built with? both have routing and they are completely different.

I know that in ASP.NET vNext we will have one codebase but for now I need the best one of the two, I think like going with ASP.NET WebAPI is it the right choice?

**Update**

I looked into it again and it seems like it won't take me a lot of time to implement the missing parts so it looks like I won't need either one of them as dependencies.

Comment: Do you intended to provide/serve your SPA client-side code with HTML fragments or JSON/XML result sets?  Or maybe some of both?  In other words, what do you want to 'consume' in the client-side code?

Comment: Well, I think it's going to be mostly HTML files but the thing to note here is that I don't use Controllers and Views in the server at all so the reason I want to implement routing is to remove these things from the process of a request and for the response, like I said for now it's going to be purely HTML. So just to describe the flow briefly, I'm thinking to do something like this Request >> Routing >> HtmlEngine >> Response. The HtmlEngine is a template engine.

Comment: If I understand correctly what it is you want to do, you might want to look at OWIN / Katana as a possible approach that seems to fit well.

Comment: Yeah, I heard about OWIN and Katana and completely forgot about it so thank you so much! you saved me quite a bit of time. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [Katana](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) and a very basic routing mechanism.